# 403 error when port forwarding

Tags: linux, networking, apache-http-server, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi

I have created a static ip on my bthub - `31.xx.xxx.17`

[image]

I have then used port forwarding with my raspberry pi device with all the major ports (ie `21,22,80, etc`)

[image]

I have set the bt firewall like this:

[image]

Then on the raspberry pi the local ip - `31.xx.xxx.21` has been set like this:

[image]

I have then edited the `/etc/network/interfaces` on my raspberry pi to:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static

address 31.xx.xxx.21
network 31.xx.xxx.16
broadcast 31.xx.xxx.23
gateway 31.xx.xxx.17

iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

When I enter the ip `31.xx.xxx.21` locally the index page works perfectly. But when I enter `31.xx.xxx.17` locally I get a `403` error. And remotely nothing appears!! I have had it all working fine a week ago but I have sinced moved from a wifi connection on my raspberry pi to an ethernet one and everything has broken! Why?

---

## update

When I access my public ip it works fine too! But that is not going to be static is it?

Comment: Depends on your ISP. Turning your router off then back on will help you determine if you have a dynamic ip. When the router turns back on it will most likely get a different ip. In other cases it may take up to 24 hours before your router gets assigned another ip.

Answer (score 0):

Check that iptables or firewall if you have one to make sure raspberry pi is not blocking incoming connections. Try accessing another service like ssh from another device to see if web server program is blocking remote connections. It could also be a firmware bug in the router. Caused by switching from WiFi to Ethernet it's uncommon but possible. If it's not too much hassle setting up your router again you could try resetting the router to defaults.